# How to include php file in a php file

Tags: php, file

Hey I would like to include a navigation.php file in my website, but i cant figure out how to include an external file in a .php file, and the only way i could find to include the navigation.php into the files was to make a copy of it in each directory.

```
<?php include("navigation.php"); ?> works when i make a copy of the navigation.php in each directory.


<?php include("http://www.mysite.net/format/navigation.php"); ?> gives me an error.
```

I would like to only have one of these navigation.php files in a "Format" directory and then make each page fetch the file and display it.

Also ill be monitoring this question for a while so just ask me if you need any additional info.

Comment: You don't want to include an external file over http. That's asking for trouble. What if the external file contained malicious code?

Comment: Yeah doing if from a url is not going to work, its by design else it will be unsafe. An easy way is to set define a constant in your index like WEB_ROOT and then use it when doing your includes. Then you never have to worry about where you are within the directory structure.

Comment: the file i want to add using the include was written by me so i doubt there will be malicious code in it...

Comment: @ilovepoker yeah i know, but malicious code does creep onto servers, used wordpress? ;p it would make it easy for injected code to include files from other hacked servers ect in one line.

Comment: read about include function =\

Answer (score 2):

Put that file *one* place. Then refer to it in each file by its proper [path](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/sharing_tools_and_toolboxes/pathnames_explained_colon_absolute_relative_unc_and_url.htm).

```
// navigation.php is in the same directory
<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
<?php include("./navigation.php"); ?>

// navigation.php is one directory below the current directory
<?php include("../navigation.php"); ?>

// navigation.php is two directories below the current directory
<?php include("../../navigation.php"); ?>
```

But this can get tedious if you have lots of files in lots of directories. The best way to do this is to use the full path to the file on the file system:

```
// Full path relative to the root of the account
<?php include("/full/path/to/navigation.php"); ?>
```

But this can get tedious if the path changes. So define a variable or constant to hold that value for you so you only need to change it in one place:

```
// In a config file
define('INCLUDE_PATH', '/full/path/to/');

// In each page after you include your config file
<?php include(INCLUDE_PATH . "navigation.php"); ?>
```

Comment: "// navigation.php is two directories below the current directory" What if its 2 'above' the current directory?

Comment: @ilovepoker A typo on my part. Corrected. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: struggling to make these codes work.... im a newbie to php so can you explain this a bit more plz? with the config file part wouldn't i have to make a copy of the config file in each directory in order for the file to access it? Also im using a online hosting service to host this site so i don't have access to the full file system.